# How to pass NSMutableArray as a reference to the part of NSMutableDictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

```
class PLCalendarEventViewController: UITableViewController {
    var event: NSMutableDictionary!

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == PLCalendarEditEventLinksSegueIdentifier {
            let tvc = segue.destinationViewController as PLCalendarEditEventLinksTableViewController
            if var links = event.objectForKey("links") as? NSMutableArray {
                tvc.data = links
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But inside my `PLCalendarEditEventLinksTableViewController`, when I try `data.addObject("new link")` then I get following error:

`mutating method sent to immutable object`.

All I need to do is when I change my `NSMutableArray` inside `PLCalendarEditEventLinksTableViewController` I change `event: NSMutableDictionary` inside `PLCalendarEventViewController`

```
class PLCalendarEditEventLinksTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data = NSMutableArray()
}
```

It is very simple in Objective-C, but how to do this in Swift?

Comment: How did you declared data in PLCalendarEditEventLinksTableViewController, with let or with var? If with let, you should change that to var.

Comment: NSMutableArray inserted into a NSDictionary is a NSArray. You must convert then to NSMutableArray after retrieving from the NSDictionary. Am I wrong?

Comment: try tvc.data = links as NSMutableArray   OR remove "?" from event.objectForKey("links") as? NSMutableArray

Comment: it didn't help. For some reason there is still `immutable object`

Comment: Don't use NSMutableArray but swift array, it's said mutable by default if it's is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be reproduced with this simple script:

```
import Foundation

let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let obj: NSMutableDictionary = ["test": NSMutableArray(array: ["foo", "bar"])]
userDefault.setObject(obj, forKey: "key")

let obj2 = userDefault.objectForKey("key") as NSMutableDictionary
if let ary = obj2["test"] as? NSMutableArray {
    ary.addObject("baz")
}
```

You can store `NSMutableArray` to `NSUserDefaults`, but when retrieve it from that, it is actually a immutable array. see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html):

> Values returned from `NSUserDefaults` are *immutable*, even if you set a mutable object as the value.

I don't know how actually `event` constructed, but regardless of that, you have to  **deep copy** it to mutable containers. AFAIK, the easiest way to do that is using `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy()`. At where you construct `event` property:

```
event = CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(nil, event, CFPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainers.rawValue) as NSMutableDictionary
```